# Не отправляется почта Debian 8

Tags: debian, exim4

У провайдера закрыт 25-й порт.

Сказали, что отправлять нужно через SMTP - smtprelay.kyivstar.ua и порт 25.
Мои действия:

1. dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
2. на первом шаге выбираю «отправка почты через smarthost; приём по SMTP или через fetchmail»
3. далее - Enter
4. на шаге «Введите IP-адрес или имя хоста почтового сервера...» ввожу «smtprelay.kyivstar.ua::25»
5. далее Enter до завершения.

По итогу скрипт:

```
mail("my-email@gmail.com", "My Subject", "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3");
```

вроде как отрабатывает (ошибок нет), но на почту ничего не приходит.

```
nano /var/log/exim4/mainlog:
2018-05-12 10:35:09 1fHP3d-0003KO-TN <= www-data@sergey-debian U=www-data P=local S=469
2018-05-12 10:35:15 1fHP3d-0003KO-TN ** my-email@gmail.com R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost X=TLS1.0:RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1$
2018-05-12 10:35:15 1fHP3j-0003Kh-51 <= <> R=1fHP3d-0003KO-TN U=Debian-exim P=local S=1578
2018-05-12 10:35:15 1fHP3d-0003KO-TN Completed
2018-05-12 10:35:15 1fHP3j-0003Kh-51 => www-data <www-data@sergey-debian> R=local_user T=mail_spool
2018-05-12 10:35:15 1fHP3j-0003Kh-51 Completed
```

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Видел такой же ваш пост на другом форуме. У меня такая же проблема.
У меня тоже Киевстар. Дали те же данные. По новой сконфигурировал Exim по похожей схеме как у вас, но результата ноль.... Письма по прежнему зависают в очереди. Вы писали на другом форуме что вопрос решен. Подскажите, как вопрос то решили?

Comment: Переконфигурировал exim # dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config, на первом шаге выбрал 2-й вариант, и далее, не помню, на каком шаге ввел данные от Киевстара

Comment: Правда, это заработало только для ноутбука, где тоже, как и на стационарном, стоит Дебиан 8. На десктопе так и не заработало.